# Need to filter events from the current week only

Tags: views, theming, datetime

I am using drupal 7 & views for a simple event agenda website. I need to display content for the current week only. How do I filter those with views? For example, I need to be able to set an event that will show only through week number 36.
thanks!

Comment: So, "current week" means up until this coming Sunday evening? Or within the next 7 days?

Comment: yes, up until the end of the calendar week, not +7 days from the given date.

Answer (score 3):

Views can do this.

Add a contextual filter for the date field you're trying to filter. In the "Preview with contextual filters" box, you will be able to specify something like "2012-W34" (Edit: or any other valid date format for that matter) to say year 2012 on week 34. Use PHP's date() function to retrieve the current week and pass that as an argument to your view. This will give you your current week while avoiding current day +/- 7 days.

Edit: When passing the argument to your view, be sure it's a string in the date format and not just a week number.

Answer (score 1):

Jimajamma's method does the job perfectly and is easily applied; only the start date should be set to `this sunday` instead of `last sunday` (or whatever you choose as the first day of the week). With `last sunday` you get the results of the entire past week if the current date is a sunday itself.
EDIT: It shows that neither 'this' nor 'last sunday' will provide consistent results. The best method to get an invariable current week frame, no matter which day is now, seems to be the one described [here](http://gamereplays.org/reference/strtotime.php) (via [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1897727/get-first-day-of-week-in-php)):

```
$start_of_week = strtotime("next monday - 1 week"); // Will return Monday of the current week starting at 00:00:00"
$end_of_week = strtotime("next monday - 1 second"); // Will return Sunday of the current week ending at 23:59:59"
```

Answer (score 0):

For the current week, Views can do this very easily by selecting a plain old filter on a date field of your choosing and then selecting `is between` for the operator and putting `last sunday` in the `date default` and `this saturday` in the `to date default`.